# Is it possible to write a Filtered Index where the column value is NOT LIKE 'X'?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization, filtered-index

I'm trying to optimize a table lookup because the execution plan shows a pretty hefty parallelized table scan. The table is called `Opportunity` and the column I'm filtering on is `Name`. Specifically I want all rows that don't have "Supplement" as part of the `Name`:

```
WHERE ([Name] NOT LIKE '%Supplement%');
```

I was looking around for a way to optimize this and came across filtered indexes which is what I need, but they don't seem to like the `LIKE` keyword. Is there an alternate way to creating a filtered index like this?

The table has ~53k rows, and when directly querying the server it takes 4 seconds to get the data, but when I query it as a linked server (which is what I need) it takes 2 minutes. In an attempt to improve this time, I moved the query out of my script that was talking to the linked server and created a view on the remote server. Still takes forever.

Here's what I've tried so far, but the SSMS says it's invalid:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [FX_NotSupplementOpportunities]
    ON      [Opportunity]([Name])
    WHERE   (([Name] NOT LIKE '%Supplement%')
            AND ([Name] NOT LIKE '%Suplement%')
            AND ([Name] NOT LIKE '%Supplament%')
            AND ([Name] NOT LIKE '%Suppliment%'));
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use `LIKE` in filtered index conditions in SQL-Server.

Comment: Is there alternate recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use a [Indexes on Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx)
an example would be:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTab](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Text] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [OK]  AS (case when NOT [text] like '%abc%' then (1) else (0) end) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTab] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_OK] ON [dbo].[MyTab] 
(
    [OK] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: thanks, for accepting but the answer of @ypercube seem to be the better one, you might chance your decision.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there are many limitations on what you can put in a condition of a filtered index.

I can't find anything specific in MSDN but this blog post by Brent Ozar: [What You Can (and Can’t) Do With Filtered Indexes](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/what-you-can-and-cant-do-with-filtered-indexes/) mentions several of the limitations:

You can't use `BETWEEN`, `NOT IN`, `CASE` expressions, `OR`.

They don't mention `LIKE` but simple testing (as you did) confirms that you can't either. You can't even use `(NOT (a >= 7))` which can be rewritten to the allowed `(a < 7)`.

One thought would be to use a case expression on a persisted column and then use the persisted columns in the filtered index - but that's another limitation of the filtered indexes!

So, what you do? The only thing that comes to mind is to create a persisted column and use it in a simple (not filtered) index. Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE  dbo.Opportunity
    ADD special_condition AS (CASE WHEN [Name] NOT LIKE '%Supplement%' 
                                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        PERSISTED;
```

Then add an index, using the column:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FX_NotSupplementOpportunities
    ON dbo.Opportunity
      (special_condition, [Name]) ;
```

and use the `(WHERE special_condition = 1)` in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen @bummi's answer because it was the closest to what I attempted, but it wasn't what I ended up using. A little explanation...

So, after many hours of trying to figure out how to make the query look-up faster I actually got it from a bunch of parallelized chunks down to two index seeks. I was super ecstatic about that, but in the end I had to scrap it. The problem is that the remote database is actually a backup of our Salesforce data. I had to go through some very complex table and column alterations pre and post sync that just didn't work correctly and would get erased each sync (every 10 minutes).

While doing all of that it eventually hit me that I was importing the data and then further formatting it again on my end. I decided instead to update the views on the remote server and format the data there as much as possible and then import it. So, I spent a couple of hours re-writing the SQL on both sides and I managed to get the ~25min script down to ~3min, which makes me very happy and satisfied.

In the end, although the query look-ups on the remote server are unoptimized they're still quite fast, mostly because on average there's no more than ~50k rows in most of the tables I'm touching...